# Python, automatically add attribute to subclass

Tags: python, inheritance

I would like to automatically add an attribute into some objects that inherit from class A.
These objects can only be instantiated from another object that contains the attribute I want to copy :

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(object):
    pass

class MyClass(MySuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        MySuperClass.__init__(self)

        b = B()
        hasattr(b, "my_attribut")  # True

        c = C()
        hasattr(c, "my_attribut")  # False, doesn't inherit from A


b = B() # Raise error, this object can't be instantiated here.
```

Maybe with a MetaClass ?

Comment: Make the constructor accept the object to copy from? `b = B(self)`

Comment: i don't want to use constructor =)

Comment: Why don’t you want to use a constructor?

Comment: This sounds like it might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - can you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve with this complicated approach?

Comment: i don't need another solution.

Comment: If you do not want solutions, don't ask.

Comment: @Dbi: What do you mean “another solution”? You don’t have a solution.

Comment: There seem to be two questions there... You want to add attributes to subclass and... raise error if the object is instantiated outside a class?

Comment: Please don’t abandon questions… if you’re not interested in getting an answer anymore, there’s a “delete” button at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

### Class attribute

If you want to add a *class* attribute, then you can indeed use a metaclass that only affects the behaviour of subclasses.

```
class MetaA(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, name_space):
        # Metaclass does nothing for A
        if not bases:
            return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, name_space)

        # Metaclass adds a class attribute to anything that inherits A
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(name_space, my_attribute='foo'))

class A(metaclass=MetaA):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

hasattr(A, "my_attribute") # False
hasattr(B, "my_attribute") # True
```

### Instance attribute

If what you want is your objects to have an *instance* attribute if their class is inherited from `A`, then metaclass will not do it. You could have a conditional statement in your `A.__init__`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        if type(self) != A:
            self.my_attribute = 'foo'

class B(A):
    pass

hasattr(A(), "my_attribute") # False
hasattr(B(), "my_attribute") # True
```